# Record voice coming of a certain PID Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyaudio, pulseaudio

I am working on text to speech algorithm, i finally made it, what this algorithm do is turn an html file

into speech, like that : `python record.py file.html`

and all good on here, but i want to run the same command on multiple files using this command :

```
python record.py file1.html & python record.py file2.html & python record.py file3.html
```

but instead of recording every audio separately i get an overlap on the output .

PS1: i am using ubuntu server, and i want to run my command on over 6000 file, the approximate time needed per file is around 20 mins bc they are a big files.

PS2: I am using pyaudio to record the voices, and here is the recording part in my code:

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
import sys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import pyaudio
import wave
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), chrome_options=chrome_options)
#selenium part 
browser.get('website')
search = browser.find_element_by_id("text-area")
search.clear()
data="this is a simple test"
search.send_keys(data)
time.sleep(2)
browser.find_element_by_id("btn").click()
print("waiting for audio")
size = len(data)/200
time.sleep(size*2)
print("audio detected")
CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
#number = len(data)
RECORD_SECONDS = size*17
WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME = 'first.mp3'
open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, "wb+")
frames = []

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE,input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

print("started recording")
for i in range(0, int(RATE / CHUNK * RECORD_SECONDS)):
    audio = stream.read(CHUNK)
    frames.append(audio)

print("end of recording")
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()

wf = wave.open(WAVE_OUTPUT_FILENAME, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```

Is there any way to record audio coming from a certain PID.

I've heard about docker containers, but i dont know if it gonna help in this situation.

Comment: Are you using one `&` because you want to do them all in parallel? What happens if you do `&&` instead? That should execute one command at a time. Might help you figure out if it's a parallel processing issue or something else.

Comment: && gonna record once in time and it's working fine, but in my case it gonna take over 80days to get the job done, so not a working solution at all, and i want to run them in parallel

Comment: Can you edit your code to include the minimal reproducible example? Specifically, what `import`s do you use and where is the code that specifically handles the input filename? I'm trying to run your code, but as presented, it looks like you open the same stream independent of filename.

Comment: i've added the informations i could, so this file is going to run for multiple times, and of course the file_name is changed on every call.

Comment: A couple things I'm seeing. I don't see the input file_name variable being used anywhere, just the output file `first.mp3`. It also looks like there's some unnecessary code (why sleep based on the size of a random string?, is the selenium part or the wave part at the bottom necessary to reproduce this problem?).

Comment: please do not bother yourself with the selenium part, that was only the version1 of my code, now the selenium part is working fine, just stuck in how to run my code for multiple files. please note that every file generated (mp3) has a different name based on the html file, so the main problem is running the record separately not the selenium part

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230756/discussion-between-wxz-and-adgogo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i did solve it was to download the audio files from the website instead of

recording them, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001434/log-in-into-website-and-download-file-with-python-requests) helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I can't get your sample code to work but I have one basic conjecture: Do you change the output filename for each of your calls? Looking at your script, that appears to not be the case. In certain cases not changing the filename may lead to garbled text.

Certain packages (e.g. [pyttsx3](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/)) do some funky stuff in order to write audio to a file that is not thread safe. That is most likely what is happening with your approach.

#### Offline text-to-speech

I've found that a pretty solid way to do this task is to just call something like [`espeak`](http://espeak.sourceforge.net/) directly.

[I've written a little package that provides a CLI for this.](https://github.com/michaelwooley/html-to-mp3) The heart of it is in this snippet:

```py
import os
import tempfile
import re

# These packages are conveniences.
# Listing builtin packages that will require a few more lines to use
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # Alt. html.parser


def text_to_mp3(text: str, outfile: str) -> None:
    """Given some text, generate an mp3 speaking the text.
    Args:
        text (str): Text to speak
        outfile (str): *.mp3 file to write
    """

    # For some reason espeak doesn't find NamedTemporaryFile files to be agreeable...
    _, text_filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=".txt")

    with open(text_filename, "w") as file:
        file.write(text)
    try:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".wav", delete=True) as wav_file:
            os.system(f"espeak -f {text_filename} -w {wav_file.name}")
            os.system(f"lame --preset insane {wav_file.name} {outfile} --silent")
    finally:
        if os.path.exists(text_filename):
            os.remove(text_filename)


def html_to_mp3(html: str, outfile: str, select: str = "body") -> None:
    """Given a string containing html, generate an *.mp3 that speaks the text.
    Args:
        html (str): HTML string
        outfile (str): *.mp3 to generate
        select (str, optional): CSS selector from which to select text. Defaults to "body".
    Raises:
        ValueError: In case the CSS selector is not present in the text.
    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features="html.parser")
    elements = soup.select(select)
    if not elements:
        raise ValueError(f"No elements found for CSS selector `{select}`")
    text = "\n".join([element.get_text() for element in elements])
    text_to_mp3(text, outfile)
```

The basic steps are:

1. Extract the text of interest from the html file using beautifulsoup
2. Call `espeak` on the text of interest and output the result to a `*.wav` file.

   - We write the text to file instead of trying to pass a big string through the command in order to sidestep issues with parsing `'`, `"`, and similar.
   - `espeak` only outputs to `wav`.
   - There are a lot of options for the voice to tinker with
3. Use [`lame`](https://lame.sourceforge.io/using.php) to convert the `*.wav` from the previous step to an mp3.

While you might already have these utilities on your computer, you can always install them (on ubuntu) with:

```sh
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lame espeak
```

#### Online text-to-speech

If you are okay with using an online text-to-speech that is connected to google, then the [`gTTS`](https://pypi.org/project/gTTS/) package works pretty well. In particular, the following works as you desire:

```sh
gtts-cli 'hello' --output hello.mp3 & gtts-cli 'world' --output world.mp3
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, you are providing me an alternative but not actually the solution of my problem, what i want is run a pyaudio script that is able to record only a certain program(ex: google chrome) not the whole output from the mic